# Can't Play mp3 file with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to play a mp3 file on click of a button but `com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!`
gets thrown.

When I tried this with a song with spaces in it's file name it threw an `illegal character` exception

Here's the code:

```
@FXML
void playSong(ActionEvent event) {
    File file = new File("/home/havoc/Music/bb.mp3");
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
    Media media = new Media("file://"+path);
    System.out.println(media.getSource());
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    player.play();
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8890)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3862)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2590)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
    at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:518)
    at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:421)
    at sample.Controller.playSong(Controller.java:136)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at javafx.media/com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:295)
    at javafx.media/com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:118)
    at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:474)
    ... 59 more
```

Comment: A file path may not be a valid url, even if you prepend `"file://"`. Use `File` to convert to an url: `file.toURI().toString()`. Also since you do not keep a strong reference to the `MediaPlayer` object, it may be garbage collected after some time stoping the audio...

Comment: I've previosly tried converting to url and still got the same error. What do you mean by strong reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried out the code on windows and it worked fine, turned out on Linux you need FFmpeg-compact54 to play media with JavaFX.

Comment: I seem to remember running into the same issue. Marking your own answer as accepted will help future me's make good use of your experience.